# Trying to check the login credentials using JDBCTemplate, But failed to Execute Sql Queries

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

Here is My Java code:

```
public User checkCredentials(String userName, String password){

    String sql="SELECT * FROM CT_LOGIN_USER_T 
      WHERE LOGIN_USER_NAME = ? AND LOGIN_USER_PASSWORD = ?".toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("Checking for Valid User."+sql);
    User user=(User)getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql, new Obje
                             ct[]{"%"+userName+"%","%"+password+"%"},
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<User>(User.class));
    System.out.println("USer in IMPL....."+user);
    return user;

}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I changed it as queryForObject and it worked....